# Unloading only specific types of database

Tags: php, mysql

There is a loop that creates a boot file:

```
<?php

$result_for_base_a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_option WHERE order_id = '$id'");
for($j = 0; $j<count($result_for_base_a->rows); $j++) {
    $product_option_value_id = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_value_id'];
    $product_option_id = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_id'];

    $result_for_base_c = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option WHERE product_option_id = '$product_option_id'");
    $product_id = $result_for_base_c->row['product_id'];
    $result_for_base_b = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value WHERE product_option_value_id = '$product_option_value_id' AND product_id='$product_id'");
    $points = $result_for_base_b->row['points'];

    $price = $result_for_base_b->row['price'];
    $counts = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['quantity'];
}
```

I need to add a rule that will create a bootable data for only those options that select.

[image]

The table has a 'type', there is a select, checkbox, radio, image, etc., But I need to loop ignored all types except select.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add condition `type = 'select'` into your select. Try something like this:

```
<?php

$result_for_base_a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_option 
    WHERE order_id = '$id' AND `type` = 'select'");

for($j = 0; $j<count($result_for_base_a->rows); $j++) {
    $product_option_value_id = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_value_id'];
    $product_option_id = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_id'];

    $result_for_base_c = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option WHERE product_option_id = '$product_option_id'");
    $product_id = $result_for_base_c->row['product_id'];
    $result_for_base_b = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value WHERE product_option_value_id = '$product_option_value_id' AND product_id='$product_id'");
    $points = $result_for_base_b->row['points'];

    $price = $result_for_base_b->row['price'];
    $counts = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['quantity'];
}
```